# How to debug keyrock

Tags: oauth, fiware, keystone

I have succesfully used the shared keyrock from filab to let my on web application to authentificate users, using oauth.
When I tried it with a second application, I get an error from FILAB web page: "Bad Request"
The error occurs after the users logs in.
Is there a way to get additional information, what was wrong with the request?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using the "authorization code grant" flow defined by the OAuth2 standard and supported by Keyrock. In that scenario, you need to provide three parameters when building the authentication URL:

- `response_type` must be `code` (or `token` when using the "implicit grant" flow), otherwise IdM will return an `unsupported_response_type` error.
- If the `client_id` exists, but the `redirect_url` doesn't match the one provided when creating the application, then a `bad request` error will be raised. This error can be raised if the `client_id` is wrong, if the `redirect_url` is wrong or if both are wrong. **This is your case.**
- If the `client_id` app doesn't exist, the IdM will return a 404 error page.
- If any of these parameters are missing in the request, the IdM will raise an `invalid_request` error.

Except for the error 404, Keyrock seems to follow the OAuth2 protocol.